# Validity of ignoring the diamagnetic $\mathbf{A}^2$ term in solids?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics

When deriving the interaction between light and solid matter, one typically uses Minimal Coupling ($\mathbf{p} \rightarrow \mathbf{p}-e\mathbf{A}$, followed by the Coulomb gauge ($\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A}=0$). Here $\mathbf{p}$ is the momentum of an electron in the solid, and $\mathbf{A}$ is the photon vector potential.

This results in an interaction Hamiltonian between the photon field and electrons in a solid of the form

$$H_{int}\sim \mathbf{J}\cdot \mathbf{A} + \frac{e^2}{2m}\mathbf{A}^2$$

Where $\mathbf{J}$ is the current operator. These terms arise from using minimal coupling on the kinetic energy term $H_{KE}=\frac{1}{2m} ( \mathbf{p}-e\mathbf{A})^2$

I've found in many notes that the second term, often called the diamagnetic term,  is neglected in solids.  For example, http://home.uchicago.edu/~tokmakoff/TDQMS/Notes/4.1._Interaction_Light-Matter_2-7-08.pdf)

The logic is that the second $\mathbf{A}^2$ term is smaller than the first, but I don't see why this is the case? Specifically, I'm thinking about ultrafast tabletop lasers in the visible or infrared range on solid-state materials where you have strong enough fields for non-linear processes, but not plasma/fusion-level strong. All of the literature on nonlinear optics seems to be focused on the $ \mathbf{J}\cdot \mathbf{A}$ term (example, Nonlinear optics by Mukamel), but why can we neglect the diamagnetic term?

What am I missing? Why is the diamagnetic term ignored here?

Comment: This is too far-afield from what I am familiar with to answer, but the slide on page 48 [of this set of slides](https://www.tcm.phy.cam.ac.uk/~bds10/aqp/lec5.pdf) talks a bit about it. I'm guessing like all arguments about neglecting higher-order terms, it only applies where something is "weak" or "small", for some definition of "weak" or "small". So there is probably some ratio of terms that decides when it is small enough to be neglected and when it is important... Your application, it may very well be important and can't be neglected.

Comment: @tpg2114, thanks. Yes it must be a question of ratios, but I don't see why $\mathbf{J}>>e\mathbf{A}$ in the case of ultrafast lasers. Perhaps a reasonable estimate for $\mathbf{J}$ in solids is needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a single particle of charge $e$ and mass $m$ you will get
$$
H_{int}=e{\bf v}\cdot {\bf A}+\frac{e^2}{2m}{\bf A}^2. 
$$
Then, one has
$$
{\bf E}=-\frac{\partial{\bf A}}{\partial t}=i\omega{\bf A}
$$
as we have considered some plane wave hindering on the solid. Then,
$$
H_{int}=e\frac{\bf v}{i\omega}\cdot{\bf E}-\frac{e^2}{2m\omega^2}{\bf E}^2.
$$
Now, you get
$$
\frac{e}{\omega}vE\gg \frac{e^2}{2m\omega^2}E^2
$$
that yields the critical field
$$
E\ll\frac{2mv\omega}{e}.
$$
This can be evaluated for an electron, assuming $v\approx c$, and will yield $E_c\approx 10^{12}\ V/m$ for visible light.

Comment: Great! Do you have some intuition for the meaning of the critical field strength here? I'm not sure how to do an apples-to-apples comparison of the $J\cdot A$ and $A^2$ terms physically.

Comment: For example, do these have some semi-classical meaning? What about quantum mechanical?

Comment: They are both parts of a Hamiltonian and can be easily compared. Did you ever compare kinetic term and potential? Who is the largest? Anyway, in this case, they both are part of the e.m. interaction and so, it is really apple-to-apple. This is commonly done in textbooks simply because is meaningful. Of course, I just did a semiclassical analysis that is fine for most of the cases. But, for your needs, a second quantized case is even more interesting as, in such a case, the dipole density comes into play and, for a macroscopic body, is an important information.

Comment: Of course, I have not found a critical field in the sense of a fundamental constant but just an estimation between two terms into a Hamiltonian in order to understand orders of magnitude.

Comment: Sorry I think you misunderstood me. I agree your math is all good and correct, I'm just having trouble understanding the situation physically. For example, it's pretty clear how to compare kinetic and potential energy intuitively as the speed of a particle in a well. When the speed is high enough, the particle can leave the well. What about the intuitive picture in this case?

Comment: The point is that the quadratic term is important just when the implied fields are high enough. You are, in such a case, in a strong field regime. There is a large research area with power lasers, that is currently active, where such a term cannot be neglected. They generally start from the Volkov solution of the Dirac (or Schroedinger) equation and do perturbation theory around such a solution. So, if you want to see such a term in action, this is the right field of application.

Comment: Let me try to rephrase one last time. What is the interpretation of ignoring the $A^2$ in semi-classical (or even classical) equations of motion? Is it equivalent to just dropping the $\mathbf{B}$ term in $\mathbf{F} = -e \mathbf{E} -e\mathbf{v}\times \mathbf{B}$?

Comment: Not at all. You have to evaluate case by case. As you have seen, I have considered a plane wave and you know that, in a plane wave, the electric and magnetic fields are proportional. Using potentials, this would be ${\bf F}=e\nabla\phi+e\partial_t{\bf A}-e{\bf v}\times{\nabla\times{\bf A}}$. Now, just fit the critical field here by noting that ${\bf k}=(2\pi\omega/c){\bf n}$, being ${\bf n}$ the unit vector in the propagation direction, and you get your answer.

Comment: ok so the conclusion is that there is no intuitive interpretation of dropping $A^2$ in the classical context, it is all just "case by case" in your viewpoint.